# 2 similar forms on the one page, $(this).find(); is getting value from the last form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 2 forms on 1 page. I am trying to get the value of the name field from the first form using jQuery but jQuery is always getting the name value from the 2nd form. The code looks like this:

```
$('#registration-form').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    $this.submit(function (event) {
        var firstName = $(this).find('input[name="firstName"]').val();
        console.log(firstName);
    });
});
```

Why is this code not working? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you got more than one `#registration-form` on the page? IDs are unique, and so if this is the case it could explain your issue. Try making `registration-form` a `class` instead.

Comment: Yes I have more than one #registration-form on the page. I will rename it to a class. I get that ID's should be unique but I feel jQuery should get what's going on in this case. Thanks so much Ryan :)

Comment: My first guess is that your forms have the same id.s

Comment: Include the HTML code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're selecting by `id` attribute, so you cannot have more than one element with the same `id`. This is why only one is found. The `each()` is also redundant in this case.

If you want to group elements use a `class` instead, although note that the `each()` is still redundant as jQuery will loop over each selected element internally so you can just attach the `submit` event handler directly, like this:

```
$('.reg-form').submit(function (e) {
    var firstName = $(this).find('input[name="firstName"]').val();
    console.log(firstName);
});
```

Comment: I have given this a go and for some reason it's not working..it's still picking up the 2nd form value. I have removed the ID and made a class, removed the each function so it's essentially identical to what you have written. Could it be something else?

Comment: Possibly, but it would be an issue in your code, as the above works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q7k3kepx/. Please check the console for errors, or edit your question to include a more complete sample of your HTML and JS

Comment: This is working great, this is just an error in my brain looking at different code but thinking it was the code I needed.